# How can I switch screen in PyQt5 by some function?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

This is main.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'main.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.0
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

import PyGravitySim.files.program as program


class Ui_main(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 200, 1920, 250))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(72)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 520, 1920, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.start_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.start_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(760, 730, 401, 131))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(30)
        self.start_button.setFont(font)
        self.start_button.setObjectName("start_button")
        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def btn_clicked(self):
        program.startProgram()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "PyGravity Sim by Woojin K"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PyGravity Sim"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Made by Woojin K"))
        self.start_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "START"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_main()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is program.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'program.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.0
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_program(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1920, 1080)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


def startProgram():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_program()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

These files are just a blank example.
I made these .py files by uic command.

I just added `startProgram()` on program.py, and import this on main.py.

If I press the start button, I get exit code -1 and the program blows out.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one QApplication instance exists in Qt, so you should never create and start to run another one. In fact, if you try to run the program in your IDE or from a shell/command prompt, it will probably return this before exiting:

> `QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running`

What you should actually do is create the Ui from the main script:

```
from program import Ui_program

class Ui_main(object):
    # ...
    def btn_clicked(self):
        self.programWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_program()
        ui.setupUi(self.programWindow)
        self.programWindow.show()
```

That said, this is *not* the way uic generated files should be used, as you should just leave them as they are and import them as modules in your actual script(s).
Read the official PyQt documentation about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) to understand how to implement ui files and their generated output.

Comment: Thanks very much for your question. I could solve this problem with your explanation.